# How to uninstall PIL from Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install Pillow for my Python (Version 2.7.12). However, I heard that PIL and Pillow cannot co-exist in the system. So I tried to uninstall PIL from my system with the following code

```
sudo pip uninstall pil
```

But it did not work and an error popped up

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name main
```

Can I ask what that means? And how can I completely remove PIL in order for me to install Pillow.

Thank you so much for the help in advanced

Tommy

Comment: Which version of `pip` do you have? (You can check running `pip --version`)

Comment: Hi Danibix, Im using 10.0.1.

Comment: Pillow is packaged as python-pil and python3-pil in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu, and it has replaced the discontinued PIL project in the default Ubuntu repositories since Ubuntu 13.04. You should uninstall pillow that you installed with pip and install python-pil and/or python3-pil instead. Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/832943/python-not-finding-file-that-exists/922495#922495

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [discussion](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5240) on Github, it seems that it has been introduced a change in pip library that breaks it.

The suggested solution for the moment is to downgrade the version of `pip` to 9.0.3

```
pip install --user --upgrade pip==9.0.3
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I tried to downgrade it using your suggest but I get the following error.      Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.3.dist-info'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Comment: @user1127763 I've updated the answer. If it doesn't work also with this method, try to run the command as superuser, using `sudo` to run the command.